# Compare timestamps in two different DataFrames with different length and then merge them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I have two Dataframes:

```
df1=

   date                col1 col2
0  2023-01-01 16:00:00 100  200
1  2023-01-01 16:15:00 120  400
2  2023-01-01 16:30:00 140  500
3  2023-01-01 16:45:00 160  700
4  2023-01-01 17:00:00 200  300
5  2023-01-01 17:15:00 430  200
6  2023-01-01 17:30:00 890  100

df2 =

   date                col3 
0  2023-01-01 16:00:00 1  
1  2023-01-01 16:15:00 1  
2  2023-01-01 17:00:00 1
```

I want to check whether `df2['date']` is in `df1['date']`. I manage to do that by using the following: `df2['date'].isin(df1['date']).all()`.

After that I want to create a new Dataframe that joins (probably with the use of `df1.join(df2)`) `df1` and `df2` and looks like this:

```
df_new=

   date                col1 col2 col3
0  2023-01-01 16:00:00 100  200  1
1  2023-01-01 16:15:00 120  400  1
2  2023-01-01 16:30:00 140  500  0
3  2023-01-01 16:45:00 160  700  0
4  2023-01-01 17:00:00 200  300  1
5  2023-01-01 17:15:00 430  200  0
6  2023-01-01 17:30:00 890  100  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

```
df_result = df.merge(df2, on='date', how='left').fillna({'col3':0})
```

Comment: `on='date'`, not `on'date'` :)